# Meteor stopped running template `rendered` functions

Tags: meteor

Im trying to run some jquery code after the template renders. But it's not working. When I run the code in the console manually, it works. Here's the js :

```
Template.PanelLayout.helpers({
    restricted: function() {
        return !Meteor.user();
    },
    authInProcess: function() {
        return Meteor.loggingIn();
    },
    canShow: function() {
        return !!Meteor.user();
    }
});

Template.PanelLayout.rendered = function() {
    $(document).ready(function() { // This is the code I want to run
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
        $('.collapsible').collapsible();
    });
}
```

Template code :

```
<template name="PanelLayout">
    {{#if restricted}}
        {{> NotFound}}
    {{else}}
        {{#if authInProcess}}
            {{> spinner}}
        {{else}}
            {{#if canShow}}
                <header>
                    {{> PanelMainNav}}
                </header>
                <main id="panel-content">
                    {{> Template.dynamic template=content }}
                </main>
            {{/if}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Im not sure but I think it's because I have added the if else statements to load the content only when the user is logged in? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's because rendered function is called after document is ready, therefore your hook `document.ready` won't work, you should remove it, so it will look like this(also `rendered` function is deprecated, use `onRendered` instead):

```
Template.PanelLayout.onRendered(function() {
   $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
   $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});
```

Comment: Thanks it's working :-) Apart from that code I also have another code on `onRendered`. But when I visit it's page again it's not loading. Only run on the first visit. It's a dynamic template and I use the flow router.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with flow-router so I don't kno what might be wrong ;/